# Getting forbidden auth when group member tries to fetch member list

Tags: android, smack, mongoose-im

I'm trying to fetch member list using getMembers() but I'm getting 'error-code: 403, forbidden-auth' the user which is trying to get a member list has is a member of a group but I if I do the same operation by the owner he can get a list successfully.

This is the my configuration for getting member list `'muc#roomconfig_getmemberlist' : [moderator, participants, visitor]`

and also it's very clearly mention in the xep-045 **"A service SHOULD also return the member list to any occupant in a members-only room; i.e., it SHOULD NOT generate a error when a member in the room requests the member list."**

So what's I'm missing here?

These are the capture packets

SENT (0):

```
<iq to='membersonlygroup@muc.domain' from='92123456@domain/Resource' id='1BO5n-74' type='get'><query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin'><item affiliation='member'></item></query></iq>
```

SMACK: RECV (0):

```
 `<iq from='membersonlygroup@muc.domain' to='92123456@domain/Resource' id='1BO5n-74' type='error'><query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin'><item affiliation='member'/></query><error code='403' type='auth'><forbidden xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'/><text xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'>Administrator privileges required</text></error></iq><r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/>`
```

**EDIT:**
 One more thing though is that a member has a role of participant but i have notice that role value is null in this case.

[image]

Comment: This is not the type of SMACK I'm familiar with but I notice that the response say `Administrator privileges required`. Could it be that the role of this user doesn't have enough privileges? I also notice that the query says `http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin` rather than `muc#roomconfig_getmemberlist`. It might help users familiar with smack to show some code.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check your room configuration at server side. 
for create room you need to use bellow configuration.
[How to send room configuration form and create persistence rooms from android using smack 4.3.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59540196/how-to-send-room-configuration-form-and-create-persistce-rooms-from-android-usin/59540197#59540197)