# How to send room configuration form and create persistence rooms from android using smack 4.3.4

Tags: android, openfire, smack, multiuserchat

I am facing problem for create persistence room and MUC, Not able to send room configuration form. Values i send that are not set to form fields and default values are send to server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        multiUserChatManager = MultiUserChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection);

        multiUserChat = multiUserChatManager.getMultiUserChat(JidCreate.entityBareFrom(roomJID));

        multiUserChat.create(Resourcepart.from(nickname));

        Form form = multiUserChat.getConfigurationForm();
        Form submitForm = form.createAnswerForm(); submitForm.getField("muc#roomconfig_publicroom").addValue("1");
        submitForm.getField("muc#roomconfig_enablelogging").addValue("1");
        submitForm.getField("x-muc#roomconfig_reservednick").addValue("0");
        submitForm.getField("x-muc#roomconfig_canchangenick").addValue("0");
        submitForm.getField("x-muc#roomconfig_registration").addValue("0");
        submitForm.getField("muc#roomconfig_passwordprotectedroom").addValue("0");
        submitForm.getField("muc#roomconfig_roomname").addValue(roomName);
        submitForm.getField("muc#roomconfig_whois").addValue("participants");
        submitForm.getField("muc#roomconfig_membersonly").addValue("1");
        submitForm.getField("muc#roomconfig_persistentroom").addValue("1");
        multiUserChat.sendConfigurationForm(submitForm);
```

This is how you can send the room configuration from and configure room.